# Parse GeoJSON file with Java Topology Suite or GeoTools

Tags: java, geotools, jts

For example, if you have a GeoJSON file like this with a polygon(simple file for the test)

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -4.658203125,
              41.343824581185686
            ],
            [
              -5.6689453125,
              39.13006024213511
            ],
            [
              -1.9335937499999998,
              39.16414104768742
            ],
            [
              -1.3623046875,
              41.21172151054787
            ],
            [
              -4.658203125,
              41.343824581185686
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The point:

```
Geometry point2 = new WKTReader().read("POINT (-3.2958984375 40.44694705960048)");
```

And you want to load the geoJSON file in your program to test in this polygon contains the point, how could you do it in Java using JTS?

---

Other option could be use GeoTools with [GeoJson](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/unsupported/geojson.html) plugin but i'm not able to parse a GeoJson file

---

**What I have tried**

Using GEOTOOLS like [this](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/unsupported/geojson.html)

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("file.geojson")), "UTF-8");
GeometryJSON gjson = new GeometryJSON();
Reader reader = new StringReader(content);
Polygon p = gjson.readPolygon(reader);
System.out.println("polygon: " + p);
```

The problem here is that polygon p only contains the last polygon of the geojson file. If this file have many polygons, how should I parse it?

Using JTS2GEOJSON like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90041/converting-parsing-geojson-into-com-vividsolutions-jts-geometry)

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("file.geojson")), "UTF-8");
System.out.println("content: " + content);
GeoJSONReader reader1 = new GeoJSONReader();
Geometry geometry = reader1.read(content);
```

This code fail is this line:

```
Geometry geometry = reader1.read(content);
```

With this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.wololo.jts2geojson.GeoJSONReader.read(GeoJSONReader.java:51)
    at org.wololo.jts2geojson.GeoJSONReader.read(GeoJSONReader.java:21)
    at org.wololo.jts2geojson.GeoJSONReader.read(GeoJSONReader.java:16)
```

This error is due i'm trying to read a FeatureCollections from GeoJson file. It works if I tried with this simple string:

```
   String content = "{\n" +
                "        \"type\": \"Polygon\",\n" +
                "        \"coordinates\": [\n" +
                "          [\n" +
                "            [\n" +
                "              -4.141845703125,\n" +
                "              40.9218144123785\n" +
                "            ],\n" +
                "            [\n" +
                "              -4.603271484375,\n" +
                "              40.002371935876475\n" +
                "            ],\n" +
                "            [\n" +
                "              -3.5595703125,\n" +
                "              39.757879992021756\n" +
                "            ],\n" +
                "            [\n" +
                "              -2.548828125,\n" +
                "              40.43858586704331\n" +
                "            ],\n" +
                "            [\n" +
                "              -3.2080078125,\n" +
                "              41.12074559016745\n" +
                "            ],\n" +
                "            [\n" +
                "              -4.141845703125,\n" +
                "              40.9218144123785\n" +
                "            ]\n" +
                "          ]\n" +
                "        ]\n" +
                "      }";
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I added more details in the main post @IanTurton

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) then you need to start thinking in terms of [DataStores](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/datastore.html) and [FeatureCollections](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/main/collection.html). There is lots of built in smarts (much of it using JTS) to handle [filtering](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/main/filter.html) etc which saves you a lot if potential issues.

```
File inFile = new File("/home/ian/Data/states/states.geojson");
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(GeoJSONDataStoreFactory.URLP.key, URLs.fileToUrl(inFile));
DataStore newDataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
String pt = "POINT (-107 42)";

FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();
SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = newDataStore.getFeatureSource(newDataStore.getTypeNames()[0]);
Filter f = ff.contains(ff.property(featureSource.getSchema().getGeometryDescriptor().getLocalName()),
    ff.literal(pt));
SimpleFeatureCollection collection = featureSource.getFeatures(f);
if (collection.size() > 0) {
  try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = collection.features()) {
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(itr.next());
    }
  }
}
```

This will need the following in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
   <artifactId>gt-geojsondatastore</artifactId>
   <version>${geotools.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
   <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
   <version>${geotools.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: it would be possible to do it using an InputStream inFile instead of File inFile? I have tried but it doesn't work here: `URLs.fileToUrl(inFile)` The way I've done is read from InputStream, create a temporary file and copy to to him but if I run this code in AWS it fails and I think is due to create a file (because in local run without problem)

Comment: No, you need either a real URL or a file converted to a URL. May be using java.tempfile might help?

Comment: That is what we are using: `File tempFile = File.createTempFile("prefix-", ".geojson"); tempFile.deleteOnExit();` and if I run it locally with apache Flink all works well. The problem is when I run it in Kinesis Data Analytics no error have been shown but the method doesn't work because I don't have any result

Comment: I think this is probably going to be a new question for AWS experts - all I can suggest is checking the file exists in the code?

Comment: Hi @IanTurton, would you help me with this question? https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/330030/146554

Comment: GeoJSONDataStoreFactory <- what is this ?

Comment: A factory for creating `GeoJSONDataStore`s?

Answer (score 2):

With the GeoJsonReader class you can read a GeoJson Geometry from a JSON fragment into a Geometry:

http://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/io/geojson/GeoJsonReader.html

Then, test whether that geometry (geojson polygon) contains the argument geometry (wkt point):

http://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html#contains(org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry)

Comment: how should I use the GeoJSONReader according to my code added at the main post?